# How do I change the language of a Wix 3.5 MSI?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, localization, wix, votive

I have created an installer with Windows Installer XML 3.5 from within the Visual Studio 2010. The installer itself works pretty well but now I would like to change it's default language from english (1033) to german (1031). Therefore I changed the language attribute within the product tag to "1031" which should do the magic as far as I know but nothing happens. The language is still english.

```
<Product Id="MyProductId" Name="NameOfMyApp" Language="1031" Version="MyVersionNumber" Manufacturer="MyCompany" UpgradeCode="MyUpgradeCode">
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: For me I had to do both, setting the de-de Culture in the Project-Properties like Jav shows in his picture and also set the Language to 1031 in the Product.wxs File.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the language (culture) on the command line when building as described here (or in the project properties when you are using Votive):

> **[WiX Tutorial - Do you speak English?](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson2.php#2.4)**

```
candle.exe SampleWixUI.wxs
light.exe -ext WixUIExtension -cultures:de-de SampleWixUI.wixobj
```

Comment: Thanks! The project properties dialog was the hint I was missing! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it in Visual Studio: Project - Properties - Build - Cultures to build.

[image: Select language for WIX installer in Visual Studio]